# mysql query - counting like terms

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySQL table is as follows:

```
ID  term  timestamp

1   foo    xxxx
2   bar    xxxx
3   bar    xxxx
4   foo    xxxx
5   foo    xxxx
6   foo    xxxx
7   xxx    xxxx
```

I wish to produce a list displaying the most common terms in order of quantity of that term

i.e. the end result:

```
foo 
bar
xxx
```

What query should I use ?  I've done some googling, but I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for - COUNT / GROUP BY etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following SQL query should provide a solution to your problem.

```
SELECT term
FROM tablename
GROUP BY term
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), term FROM table GROUP BY term ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT term, Count(*) AS cnt FROM mytable GROUP BY term ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` is correct. Try this:

```
SELECT term FROM table
GROUP BY term
ORDER BY COUNT(term) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TERM
FROM @table
GROUP BY TERM
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5 --replace with number you want
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query should do it:

```
SELECT term FROM my_table GROUP BY term ORDER BY COUNT(term) DESC;
```